# Is it ok to have unused parameters in C functions?

Tags: c

Is it ok to leave the parameters unused?
I'm trying to run the function like this:

```
void encoder();
void encoder(int argc, FILE* inputFP, FILE* outputFP);
```

Is there a need for å secound function, one for dealing with stdio and one for dealing with files? When I try to run
`void encoder(int argc, FILE* inputFP, FILE* outputFP);` without any arguments I get errors:

````
error: too few arguments to function â€˜void encoder(int, FILE*, FILE*)â€™
         encoder();```
````

Comment: I need to be able to run encoder directly from another program in my project. Also should inputFile be const?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: @Richard Your English is perfectly fine. But you have not explained the problem very well. With so little information it's impossible to answer your question. I could say that there are situations where it's perfectly ok to not use the arguments, but I cannot say if any of those situations applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it ok to have unused parameters in C function?*

Yes.

Still, why not have `encoder()` take two `FILE*` instead of the names, then do (pseudo code):

```
main(argc, argv)
  FILE * fp_in, * fp_out

  if argc == 2
    fp_in = open argv[1], "r"
  else
    f = stdin

  if argc == 3
    fp_out = open argv[3], "w"
  else
    fp_out = stdout

  encoder fp_in, fp_out
```

Comment: I also need to be able to run encoder() directly from another program to read/write stdin/out

Comment: @Richard: How would you call a function from another program? Or do you mean "code" instead of "program", where the latter I considered compiled code.

Comment: I mean another file in my project. Maybe the whole CLion project is one program? Sorry for my bad english. I have a testfile where I need to run encoder() to read from stdin and do some en/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the general question in the title - yes, it's okay not to use all the parameters passed to a function, although it may be confusing to future maintainers.

For this specific case, instead of passing an argument count, I'd recommend using special names for the input and output files to indicate standard streams.  It's a common convention among *nix command line utilities to use `"-"` to specify reading from standard input:

```
xmllint --format some_ugly_wad_of_xml | vi -
```

The above command pretty prints some XML and then passes the pretty-printed version to vi to edit (something I've had to do a lot lately).  So instead of passing an `argc`, just pass the filenames and examine them to determine what to do:

```
if ( !strcmp( inputFile, "-" ) )
  inputStream = stdin;
else
  inputStream = fopen( inputFile, "r" );
```

This way you're not leaving any parameters "unused".

Answer (score 0):

It is better to open files and read all content and fetch to variables. So you can free (close) the file and dance. After close the file, freely make stuff.

Comment: Some times I will need to run encoder() without passing in anything